# QTextEdit расширение по контенту

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть `QTextEdit` с фиксированной шириной. Нужно, чтобы при заполнении его текстом он расширялся вверх, однако просто включается скролл бар. Много гуглин, но ничего, что помогло, не нашел.
Написал такой костыль

```
connect(text_input, &CSTextEdit::textChanged, [this]()
{
    int height = QFontMetrics(text_input->font())
            .boundingRect(QRect(),
                          text_input->alignment(),
                          text_input->toPlainText())
            .height();
    height = height > 47 ? height : 47;

    text_input->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    text_input->setMaximumHeight(height);
});
```

Но, оказалось, что перенос строки только визульный и весь этот текст является одной строкой, следовательно высота остается неизменной.

Comment: А что мешает написать свой textedit, с таким поведением, как вам нужно?

Comment: @awesome вот я и спрашиваю как это адекватно сделать

Comment: Отнаследоваться от QTextEdit и переопределить необходимые вам методы.

Comment: @awesome, можно больше конкретики? Я знаю как это делается, но не знаю какие методы нужно переопределить, чтобы это нормально работало без костылей